# Execute vectorized function on multiple cores

Tags: python, numpy

I have some function `f(x,y)` which I have vectorized with `numpy.vectorize` command. I have made some grid values of x and y for which I want the function to be evaluated. My program looks like this:

```
from numpy import vectorize,meshgrid, linspace

@vectorize
def f(x,y):
    pass

x = linspace(0,10)
y = linspace(0,10)
X, Y = meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X,Y)
```

When I look at the system monitor on evaluation time  (for example with `htop` on Ubuntu) I see that only one core is being used. What are the options to get most juice of system on such computation?

Comment: what does your f(x,y) do? instead of using @vectorize, it is better to implement your function so that it can handle ndarray arguments, since numpy.vectorize is bad

Comment: The python interpreter runs on only one core, though `numpy` can use a multi-core setup (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991014/numpy-on-multicore-hardware). A simple way to make use of multiple cores is to use something like the `multiprocessing` module.

Comment: Generally the `f(x,y)` integrates some other function `g(T,x,y)` along T with `scipy.integrate.quad`. Why numpy.vectorize is bad? It makes coding much easier!

Comment: Okay how to implement vectorize function in order to use multiple cores?

Answer (score 3):

Using `numpy.vectorize` is not usually a good idea.  It doesn't parallelize anything, and in fact the performance is generally not even very good because of the way it works (as explained [in its documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)).  So instead, you need to work on making your `f(x,y)` function vectorized internally, or implement it as a module in C or C++ or Fortran etc.

If you want to truly use multiple cores in Python, your best bet is either to use the `threading` module if your function is implemented in C, or `multiprocessing` if you're trying to run native Python (including NumPy).

Comment: (+1 for what's in the answer.) If `numexpr` can handle the function `f(x, y)`, that can be the easiest way of using several cores.